ReactJS - useState object loses getters when it is updated
I have a useState initialized to an object of type ExampleObject. This class has many properties (also nested) that make use of javascript's getters and setters. I use the getters all around my code in order to access the useState's properties:
const Component = ({data}) => {

    const [example, setExample] = useState(ExampleObject(data.p1,data.p2))

    return(
        {example.property2}
        <ChildComponent1
            example = {example}
            setExample = {setExample}
        />
        <ChildComponent2
            example = {example}
            setExample = {setExample}
        />
    )
}

export class ExampleObject {
    constructor(p1, p2) {
        this._property1 = p1;
        this._property2 = p2;
    }

    get property1(){
        return this._property1
    }

    set property1(property1){
        this._property1 = property1
    }

    get property2(){
        return this._property2
    }

    set property2(property2){
        this._property2 = property2
    }

Some of my child components update the example useState with its setter. I copy the useState's content into another variable, update that variable and then use the setter:
const ChildComponent1 = ({example, setExample}) => {

    const [textContent, setTextContent] = useState(example.property1)

    const handleTextContent = (event) => {
        setTextContent(event.target.value)
    }

    useEffect(()=> {
        let newExample = { ...example }
        newExample.property1 = textContent
        setExample(newExample)
    }, [textContent, example])

    return(
         <textarea
              value={textContent}
              onChange={handleTextContent}>
         </textarea>
    );
}

This generates a problem, the useStae is updated but its setters are lost making the whole code wrong. example.property2 in the RootComponent hands out an undefined error (should be changed to example._property) and the same goes for example.property1. I would like to keep using javascript's getters as it is good practice to do so. Is there a way to set a useState object without losing them?

Why are you putting a class into state? You don't want to be mutating state data like this.

@evolutionxbox I'm doing this because the example useState holds all the data relative to my tool. This data can be changed by user input and it has to simultaneously trigger a re-render

Avoid putting classes into state, and don't mutate state directly.

In addition to the things others have already said, this code won't even run (at least not as posted) in strict mode, you don't declare newExample anywhere, and you're calling a class without new. This code shouldn't even be able to run. You don't need useEffect at all. It also isn't clear why you have local component state. There are tons of mistakes/misconceptions here about how Javascript and React work, any of which could be your problem, all of which will need to be fixed.

Thanks for the feedback @JaredSmith. I've corrected the question adding let newExample. I understand that the only way to keep the getters and setters is to declare new ExampleObject. What do you mean by local component state?

What do you mean by local component state? - this is one of the fundamentals of react. I would strongly suggest reading https://react.dev/learn/adding-interactivity

Spreading a class instance into an object like you're doing with this statement:
newExample = { ...example }

..will only do a shallow copy of the class instance's properties, not it's methods. So you're basically losing all getters and setters as soon as you use the spread operator to create a new object, and the new object will not be an instance of ExampleObject anymore.

This. Among other things.
